# Display the beginning of a scope when it is out of screen

Tags: minibuffer, c++, programming

I would like to display the opening part of a scope when this one get out of screen.

Example:

```
namespace a  
{  
...  
--------------------- <- display frame 
...                 |  
}*                  | * when cursor is here display "namespace a" in the minibuffer
---------------------   or on screen
```

This could work for many programming language but I am mainly thinking of C++.

To clarify a bit more and for those who know VS, I would like a similar feature as what exist for Visual Studio. i.e. positioning the cursor at the end of a scope display the beginning of the scope at the top of the edit buffer.

Is this feature already existing somewhere ?

Comment: I'm curious, did my answer help?

Comment: @TuDo yes! I just had time to have a look. I already had semantic and just turning on global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode worked nicely. Thanks. My problem now is that the color does not make the headerline readable..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are writing C/C++/Java/Emacs Lisp/Python, then [semantic-sticky-func-mode](http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html#sec-9-2) will do what you want.

**NOTE**: This seems to be working with CEDET from Git, not stock CEDET currently in Emacs 24.4. To get Emacs from Git:

> git clone http://git.code.sf.net/p/cedet/git cedet

And load CEDET first above everything else in your init file:

```
(load-file (concat user-emacs-directory "/cedet/cedet-devel-load.el"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (concat user-emacs-directory "cedet/contrib"))
(load-file (concat user-emacs-directory "cedet/contrib/cedet-contrib-load.el"))
```

When enable, this mode shows the function point is currently in at the first line of the current buffer. This is useful when you have a very long function that spreads more than a screen, and you don't have to scroll up to read the function name and then scroll down to original position.

It displays **full** function interface (return type, function name and parameters), not just function name.

To enable it, put this code in your init file:

```
(require 'semantic)
(semantic-mode 1)
(global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode 1)
```

**UPDATE**: One of the problem with current `semantic-stickyfunc-mode` is that it does not display all parameters that are scattered on multiple lines. To solve this problem, I created the package [stickyfunc-enhance](https://github.com/tuhdo/semantic-stickyfunc-enhance).

**DEMO**:

Here is a demo in C:

[image: semantic-sticky-func-mode-c]

Here is a demo in Emacs Lisp:

[image: semantic-sticky-func-mode-elisp]

**UPDATE**: Alternatively, you can use [helm-semantic-or-imenu](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#sec-9). When you are inside a function and run the command, the cursor is placed right at the function in the list, so you can always see the full function interface. DEMO:

- First, I use `helm-semantic-or-imenu` to move to the function `helm-define-key-with-subkeys` and move point there.
- Then, I start `helm-semantic-or-imenu` again and `helm-define-key-with-subkeys` is pre-selected.
- Then, I move point to the variable helm-map and execute `helm-semantic-or-imenu` again on two function: helm-next-source and helm-previous-source. This time, instead of showing the current semantic tag I'm operating in (which is helm-map), it shows the other two tags in Helm Semantic buffer. This is because I supplied a prefix argument before running the command.

Also this demo is in Emacs Lisp, it works for C/C++ as well and it's more flexible if you got a really long function interface.

[image: helm-semantic-or-imenu]

Comment: How did you get this to work for Lisp (Elisp in particular)? I evaluated your code in `emacs -Q` but I don't get the behavior you describe when I browse, e.g., `org.el`.

Comment: I updated the answer. You should try it with Semantic from bzr.

Comment: Totally off topic.  Thank you for introducing me to Nyan mode.  My coding will never be the same again.

Answer (score 6):

You can turn on `which-function-mode` by doing

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `which-function-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

To make the setting permanent, add

```el
(which-function-mode 1)
```

to your init-file.

From the documentation:

> Toggle mode line display of current function (Which Function mode). [...]
>
> Which Function mode is a global minor mode.  **When enabled, the
>   current function name is continuously displayed in the mode line**,
>   in certain major modes.

**Note**: The name doesn't really suggest it, but this works not only for "functions", but for other types of scopes as well. For example, in `org-mode`, `which-function-mode` displays the heading of the current subtree.

Comment: Thanks! I like the function name beeing displayed in the mode line. Some case were not working very well though. Like method in a struct in a namespace, the namespace name only was displayed